# My Logo is hiding behind the camera position?

Tags: flutter

**How can I avoid the camera position while building a screen? My Logo is hiding behind the camera.** [image: camera position problem while building flutter app]

This is what I've tried:

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size(double.infinity, 100),
            child: AppBar(
              title: Image.asset(
                Constants.kLogoPath,
                height: 40,
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              actions: [
                TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Skip"))
              ],
            )));
```

Comment: Wrap your `Scaffold` body (or even a whole `Scaffold` if you want) in a `SafeArea` widget

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear but `SafeArea` might solve the issue for you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkF0TQJO0bA

Comment: My logo is hidden by the camera position. Now how can I avoid this position? 
-That was my question and I think you're clear now.

Comment: SafeArea handles the status bar only not the in-display camera. Is there any way to get out of this problem?

Comment: Use real devices your problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

use `SafeArea` widget to avoid camera

```
SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size(double.infinity, 100),
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            actions: [TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Skip"))],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: SafeArea can not solve my problem. The logo is still under the camera position.

Answer (score 1):

I only faced this problem while using an emulator. But while using real devices this problem is fixed automatically.